# How to display a HTML template if users navigates through mobile?

Tags: jquery, mobile

I have two types of HTML files.

The first type is for computer users.
The second type is for mobile users. It's coded in jQuery Mobile.

The first type is the one uploaded in the server. How do I code that if a user navigates through a mobile (iphone, samsung, whatever...) the HTML for mobiles was displayed?

Thanks.

Comment: it's everything coded in HTML but i know quite php, any other way of making this without php?

Comment: I have add an answer in php

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP, you can use the [Mobile Detect](http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/) library. It's quite easy and keeps up to date. Also allows to use `isTablet()` and others.

You can do something along the lines of:

```
include 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect();
if ($detect->isMobile()) {
  includeMobilePage();  // Any mobile device.
} else {
  includeDesktopPage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it based on width.. like so:

```
if($(window).width() < 480){
 window.location = "mobile.yoursite.com"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your site content is the same for both mobile and regular users, and you just need different layout, I suggest looking into CSS media queries and building a responsive design site.

For example, in your CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 700px) { … }
```

Any CSS directive you put within those brackets will only apply when the screen is at least `400px` wide, but less than `700px` wide.

This example and others can be found here:  http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Answer (score -1):

usually I use this code in php and I put all my jquery mobile inside a folder called smartphone

```
<?php 
$mobile_browser = '0';
if (preg_match('/(up.browser|up.link|mmp|symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|phone|android|ipad)/i', strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))) {
    $mobile_browser++;
}

if ((strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']),'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml') > 0) or ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE']) or isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PROFILE'])))) {
    $mobile_browser++;
}    

$mobile_ua = strtolower(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 0, 4));

$mobile_agents = array(
    'w3c ','acs-','alav','alca','amoi','audi','avan','benq','bird','blac',
    'blaz','brew','cell','cldc','cmd-','dang','doco','eric','hipt','inno',
    'ipaq','java','jigs','kddi','keji','leno','lg-c','lg-d','lg-g','lge-',
    'maui','maxo','midp','mits','mmef','mobi','mot-','moto','mwbp','nec-',
    'newt','noki','oper','palm','pana','pant','phil','play','port','prox',
    'qwap','sage','sams','sany','sch-','sec-','send','seri','sgh-','shar',
    'sie-','siem','smal','smar','sony','sph-','symb','t-mo','teli','tim-',
    'tosh','tsm-','upg1','upsi','vk-v','voda','wap-','wapa','wapi','wapp',
    'wapr','webc','winw','winw','xda ','xda-');

if (in_array($mobile_ua,$mobile_agents)) {
    $mobile_browser++;
}

if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['ALL_HTTP']),'OperaMini') > 0) {
    $mobile_browser++;
}

if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'windows') > 0) {
    $mobile_browser = 0;
}

if ($mobile_browser > 0) {
   header("Location: smartphone/");
}
```

Comment: User-agent sniffing is a terrible way to go about this.  You will not catch everything, and will inevitably catch things you don't want.  In addition, the question says nothing about PHP.

Comment: ok but I have only post the method that I'm using.. and it works very fine. And he said that can be in php in the comment but thanks for the leak I can do bettere this check @Brad